# Update date to a specific format tsql error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to add a current date to and existing data table and this date needs to be in a specified format 'DDMMYYYY'. The column in the table is of the datatype 'date'.

My approach is as follow to which I get the error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Code

```
DECLARE @DateNow VARCHAR(10)

SET @DateNow = REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103), '/', '')

UPDATE UserTable
SET DateCreated =  CONVERT(date, @DateNow, 104)
WHERE EmployeeNumber = 'emp00001'
```

I am a bit rusty in SQL so sorry if this approach seems silly

Regards

Comment: just as confirmation: does DateCreated has date datatype in UserTable?

Comment: Yes, it does have date datatype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you converting a `DATETIME` returned by `GETDATE()` into a `VARCHAR(10)` first, and then back into a `DATE`?? This seems utterly point- and needless....

Try this instead:

```
DECLARE @DateNow DATE

SET @DateNow = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)

UPDATE dbo.UserTable
SET DateCreated = @DateNow
WHERE EmployeeNumber = 'emp00001'
```

and SQL Server is usually nice enough to not even require any of this converting at all - this will work just fine, too:

```
UPDATE dbo.UserTable
SET DateCreated = GETDATE()   -- or preferably: SYSDATETIME()
WHERE EmployeeNumber = 'emp00001'
```

The `GETDATE()` output (or preferably: `SYSDATETIME()` as of SQL Server **2008** or newer) will be adapted to match the datatype of your `DateCreated` column (as long as it's something date-related, of course)

**Update:** if you need to convert the `DATE` to a `DDMMYYYY` format for output, I'd use this:

```
SELECT 
     REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CreatedDate, 104), '.', '')
```

which converts today's date into

```
27112014
```

or if you're using SQL Server **2012** and newer, you can use the `FORMAT` function:

```
SELECT FORMAT(CreatedDate, 'yyyyMMdd')
```

Comment: Thanks. The tricky part for me is getting it into the format of DDMMYYYY. I tried this SET @DateNow = CAST(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103), '/', '')AS DATE)  but still get the same error Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: @Arianule: if the column is a `DATE` - it doesn't **have** a format. `DATE` is stored as binary data in SQL Server .....

Comment: Thats right...I realise this now, thanks. When exporting this data I will display it in the required format.